# How to get application folder when using Cordova / PhoneGap Build?

Tags: cordova

I'm building a phone gap app that has an update feature. The app is initially installed and contains a number of images separated into three folders. What I need is to be able to download new images, and place them into those specific folders...

So, my first need is to get the actual application folder on the device. So far I've not found much info on this...

Thanks!

OK, so still trying and not getting that far. I get a fileSystem object and from that I am tracing the root like so:

```
var dirEntry = fileSystem.root;
alert(dirEntry.name);
```

But all I get is: sdcard

Obviously that's not going to work. Can anyone give me a hint here?

Still trying to get this working and I found this info:
If there is no SDCARD present in the phone the persistent file system path returned will be:

/data/data/{package name}
where {package name} is the package attribute in the manifest tag in your androidManifest.xml file.

Does this make ANY sense? Not to me... If there is an sdcard, which there will be 99% of the time, how the heck do I get to my application folder?

Comment: There is a pretty good listing of directory locations on the Cordova File plugin's GitHub page: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md

Answer (score 0):

use

> alert('entry2' + cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory);